# Showing specific output from Arista switch debug counters

Tags: switch, counter

The command for Arista switch

```
sh platform fm6000 counters interface et 1
```

will display a long list of debug counters. Is it possible to just display the counters I want, as if I were to use grep to just display the specific counter?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can pipe to grep natively in EOS.

For example:

```
show platform fm6000 counters interface ethernet1 | grep IPv6
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx octets with unicast L2 DMACS              0
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx octets with broadcast L2 DMACS            0
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx octets with multicast L2 DMACS            0
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx pkts with unicast L2 DMACS                0
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx pkts with broadcast L2 DMACS              0
Ethernet1   valid IPv6 rx pkts with multicast L2 DMACS              0
Ethernet1   rx octets in valid IPv6 pets                            0
```

Another useful tip would be using pipe to nz, as in "non-zero", so you do not see any line with counters that are only 0.

```
sh int count incoming | nz
Port                 InOctets     InUcastPkts     InMcastPkts     InBcastPkts
Et7                 946979594               0          131677               0
Et8                   4208900               0           33307            4656
Et9                  56549330               0           38990            4656
Et46                  6302834               0           38464              13
Et47                  4358450               0           23285               0
Et48                  8870985               0           42911               0
Ma1                  32218384          235583           29735           69495
Po733                13065988               0           80558               1
```